# UILabel shifts right when animating superview using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, autolayout, uilabel

In the .gif below, I have a view that is the same size as the device screen (with the beige background).  That view has a subview (with the purple background), which I've positioned using Auto Layout. It's been set to be the same width as its superview, with a constant value of -18, and its CenterX value set to be the same as its superview, so it's centered with 9pts of space on each side.

Inside of that view, is a UILabel, also positioned using Auto Layout. It's been set to be the same width as its superview, with a constant value of -20, and its CenterX the same as its superview, so it's centered with 10pts of space on each side.

When the user taps on the purple view, I want to perform a multi-step animation, where the first step involves the purple view expanding to be the same width as its superview.

I'm doing this using the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    [constraint setConstant:0.0];
    [view.superview layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

The problem (as seen in the first .gif), is that the UILabel immediately shifts right, and then gradually comes back to center as the animation plays out.

**Incorrect animation:**

[image: Incorrect animation:]

In this next .gif, however, the animation performs correctly. I'm using the same code to perform the animation, but instead of making the UILLabel be the same width as its superview (minus the 20pts), I hard-code the width to be a static value, using 0 as the constraint multiplier, and 357 as the constant value.

**Correct animation:**

[image: Correct animation:]

This accomplishes the effect that I'm looking to achieve, but I'd rather not hard-code the width of the UILabel (plus I'm very curious why it's acting this way).

Any ideas?